# Nomenclature "Material System"

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, material-science

This is just a quick question about nomenclature from General Relativity. Most textbooks refer to "material systems";

1) Does a material system have to be a system with mass? or can it just be a system with energy-momentum (say photons?);

2) Can material systems be discretised, or do they have to be continuous bodies (e.g. dust,fluid)?

3) Does anyone have a reference to a substantial definition of a material system?

Any guidance appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Which textbooks? Which pages?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no universally agreed definition of *material system* and I suspect different authors will use the term in different ways. In my experience it means anything that has a non-zero stress-energy tensor, so it includes any distribution of matter and energy. This would include any arrangement of photons. However it would exclude things like [geons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geon_(physics)).